# ClassCastException in LingPipe

Tags: classcastexception, lingpipe

I am serializing a trained model using

```
TradNaiveBayesClassifier classifier = new TradNaiveBayesClassifier(categories,tokenizerFactory,categoryPrior,tokenInCategoryPrior,lengthNorm);
```

then I trained it and compiled it using

```
AbstractExternalizable.compileTo(classifier,new File(modelPath));
```

When I read in the model using

```
TradNaiveBayesClassifier decompClassifier = (TradNaiveBayesClassifier)AbstractExternalizable.readObject(new File(modelPath));{
```

I get a ClassCastException. Any ideas?

Comment: The exception I get is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aliasi.classify.TradNaiveBayesClassifier$CompiledBinaryTradNaiveBayesClassifier cannot be cast to com.aliasi.classify.TradNaiveBayesClassifier
 at com.wlodarczak.twitter.BayesClassifier.evaluate(BayesClassifier.java:102)
 at com.wlodarczak.twitter.BayesClassifier.run(BayesClassifier.java:158)
 at com.wlodarczak.twitter.BayesClassifier.main(BayesClassifier.java:163)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I had to upcast to BaseClassifier:

```
        BaseClassifier<CharSequence> eval = (BaseClassifier<CharSequence>)AbstractExternalizable.readObject(new File(modelPath));
        evaluator = new BaseClassifierEvaluator<CharSequence>(eval, cat, storeInputs);
```

Then I couldn't use the JointClassifierEvaluator any more, I had to use the BaseClassifierEvaluator.

Comment: If you don't know the type of a deserialized object, you can check with `Object.getClass()`.